# duplicated string in R

Tags: string, r

i have a vector in a data.frame like this

```
language     
Enlish
English, Spanish
English,English
English, Spanish
English,Chinses,Spanish,English
Spanish,Chinese,Spanish
English,Spanish, Chinese
......
```

There are more than 1000 rows in this vector and contain different types of languages. I want to delete all duplicated ones.I hope it can looks like this:

```
language
English,
English,Spanish,
English,
English,Spanish
English,Chinese,Spanish
Spanish,Chinese
English,Spanish, Chinese
......
```

I want to get the result with R. Thanks for help!

Comment: Assuming `dat` is your data.frame, please show the output of `str(dat)`. Otherwise it is hard to tell in what form your data is.

Comment: Yeah I assumed it was pasted character strings but this isn't necessarily the case as a dataframe will let you have a column of vectors (e.g., `x <- mtcars[1:2, 1:2]; x$y <- list(letters, 1:5); x`).

Comment: Assuming df is my data.frame, the output of str(df) is factor. When I use strsplit, there is always a error: Error in strsplit(df$language, ",\\s*") : non-character argument. I don't know why

Comment: Wrap it with `character` then.  The error message is pretty useful here.  See `?strsplit` and it tells you x should be a character vector.  Please use `dput` on your data to avoid these extended discussions.

Comment: solved it! Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach:

**Your data:**

```
language <-readLines(n=7)    
Enlish
English, Spanish
English,English
English, Spanish
English,Chinses,Spanish,English
Spanish,Chinese,Spanish
English,Spanish, Chinese
```

**Code:**

```
lang2 <- strsplit(language, ",\\s*")
## Keep as a list of vectors (more flexible)
lapply(lang2, unique)
## Or paste it together to match your output:
sapply(lapply(lang2, unique), paste, collapse = ",")

## > sapply(lapply(lang2, unique), paste, collapse = ",")
## [1] "Enlish"                  "English,Spanish"        
## [3] "English"                 "English,Spanish"        
## [5] "English,Chinses,Spanish" "Spanish,Chinese"        
## [7] "English,Spanish,Chinese"
```